# Brother MFC inkjet smearing / not printing properly after cleaning the print head

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, brother-printer

I have a Brother MFC-J470DW printer. Like a year ago, it started smearing (horizontal lines, black ink only). Running the cleaning program didn't help much. Since I also have access to a printer at the office, my usage of my brother printer became rather rare, however, the smearing did not get worse, as far as I can tell. Then, a month ago, I moved to a different flat and due to that, my brother printer remained disconnected and completely unused for a few weeks. I know that this is considered "bad" for inkjet printers. Yesterday, I connected it again. If the smearing got worse during this period, then not much. I searched for instructions on YouTube what one can do to get rid of the smearing and found several videos which suggested using a (slightly-wet or dry) lint-free paper towel to clean the print head. So here is the chronology:

1. I used both, first the slightly wet towel, then the dry one. After that, I printed a test page and the **smearing of black ink was gone!** However, **magenta was not printed at all.**
2. I ran a full cleaning program (black and color). Since then, the printer **fails to print almost any black and yellow ink**, although **magenta has returned**.
3. I re-ran the cleaning program for the black ink several times, as well as tried cleaning the print head a few times more, **but nothing changed.**

Is there anything I can do to fix my printer?

Comment: Maybe you need to replace the ink cartridges.

Comment: The black ink cartridge is fresh, I only inserted a new one yesterday.

Comment: How many years does your Electronic Device have? Lately, anything is failing sooner than four to five years.

Comment: 4–6 years @DOBRESCU_Mihai However, I disagree, age makes mechanical failure more likely, but it doesn't cause it. Age cannot be fixed. Mechanical failure is caused by things which can be fixed.

Comment: We would suggest that you could edit your question in order to make it easier to read. It is difficult to follow what exactly your actions have been, which colors have started disappearing and which colors have started reappearing. First of all, _YouTube_ Videos are not the best replacement for an experienced Professional Printer Repair Shop. Either you could take your printer to a Professional Printer Repair Shop, or you could buy a new one. Four to six years is an old age for any kind of failures.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Thanks, I edited the question to point out the chronology more cleanly. I already contacted a professional printer repair shop, but they rejected to work on my inkjet printer.

Comment: Yeah, @theV0ID, people are acting very strangely these days. We have had ourselves some kind of Software Issues related to our _Canon_ _i-Sensys_ _MF4010_ Laser Multi-Functional Printer in the beginning of the current year. The Device Drivers were not working properly. Firstly, we have attempted to contact some helping web-sites and eventually we have reached the official _Canon_ support web-site. Still, all of our attempts of reaching some kind of help were entering some kind of a black hole. Eventually, we have managed to solve the Device Drivers Issues on our own. Good luck in your quest!